# android nougat accessibility permission

Tags: android, accessibility, android-7.1-nougat

On Android Lollipop and below I could ask the user to grant me an  accessibility permission to prevent the uninstall of the APK file.

On the new OS version "Nougat" I've found out that the user can uninstall the application, in-fact the user can uninstall/disable most of the application.

Is there a way to prevent the user from de-activate/uninstall the application?

Comment: I was just curious why someone wants to restrict the user to uninstall their apps from their device? My suggestion to you is do not restrict the user from what they want to do. Tip for you : There is something called Android Device Admin. Try that - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#developing

Comment: What's the application package?